# align image inside textView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

i'm wondering how i can implement something like following where the users profileimage is inside the textview. At the moment i've created a customTableViewCell which holds a textView.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the text to flow around the image? I.e., in your image above, align with the left edge of the image starting from the 4th or so line?

Comment: yes it should flow around

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding imageView inside the textview, make imageView and textview are subviews of u r customTableViewCell.

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0 40.0,40);
textview.frame = CGRectMake(45.0,0.0,self.view.width-45,40);
[self addSubview: imageView];
[self addSubview: textview];
```

Comment: But how will the text then align around the image?